# Can't install keytouch on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: apt, keyboard, wine, settings, system-settings

I am very new to Ubuntu (I just installed it), and I'm having some issues with the keyoboard.

I have a Microsoft Natural Ergonomic Keyboard 4000 v1.0 (US International layout), but I can't install *keytouch* in order to use the custom keys. This is what I get:

```
cretino@Kibe:~$ sudo apt-get install keytouch keytouch-editor
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package keytouch
E: Unable to locate package keytouch-editor
```

I also get the following message when trying the .deb file:

`Unable to install keytouch: The following packages have unmet dependencies:`

(nothing after this, which seems odd).

*keytouch* seems to be a bit outdated, and the last similar problem I found in AskUbuntu is from 2015; but I'm unaware of other possible packages that could replace it.

Another thing that's bothering me is having to hit the space bar after pressing the apostrophe on the keyboard, otherwise it won't work (such as in can't, don't, won't and so on) or even return an accented consonant (such as sheś, Iḿ, weŕe...). I never had this issue on Windows and don't know how to fix it.

Oh, I also tried using wine to install the Windows app, but it didn't work either. That's what I got:

```
cretino@Kibe:~/Downloads$ wine MouseKeyboardCenter_64bit_ENG_14.41.exe
wine: created the configuration directory '/home/cretino/.wine'
0048:err:ole:StdMarshalImpl_MarshalInterface Failed to create ifstub, hr 0x80004002
0048:err:ole:CoMarshalInterface Failed to marshal the interface {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}, hr 0x80004002
0048:err:ole:apartment_get_local_server_stream Failed: 0x80004002
0050:err:ole:StdMarshalImpl_MarshalInterface Failed to create ifstub, hr 0x80004002
0050:err:ole:CoMarshalInterface Failed to marshal the interface {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}, hr 0x80004002
0050:err:ole:apartment_get_local_server_stream Failed: 0x80004002
0050:err:ole:start_rpcss Failed to open RpcSs service
0040:err:setupapi:SetupDefaultQueueCallbackW copy error 1812 L"@wineusb.sys,-1" -> L"C:\\windows\\inf\\wineusb.inf"
Could not find Wine Gecko. HTML rendering will be disabled.
Could not find Wine Gecko. HTML rendering will be disabled.
wine: configuration in L"/home/cretino/.wine" has been updated.
00f0:err:seh:NtRaiseException Unhandled exception code c0000005 flags 0 addr 0x43116b
```

Thanks in advance if anybody can help me!

**EDIT: Turns out I didn't really need to install anything. I can customise the keys using the native settings.
Sorry for being a n00b! Hehe**

Comment: Try installing the `.deb` file with apt instead.  `sudo apt install ./nameofdebfile.deb` that way it should install the dependencies.  However, it has not been officially added to the 22.04 repos so some of the dependencies may not work.  I did a test install and it seemed to work for me, but I don't have your keyboard so I cannot fully test it out.

Comment: However, if you are willing to try out Xubuntu (Xfce4) there is under the Keyboard settings in the layout the Microsoft Natural Ergonomic 4000